# Where can I find a complete tutorial on setting up a postfix mail server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I am trying to find a complete / solid guide on setting up a Postfix server on Ubuntu 11.04 Server.

I want to install using MySQL so I need one that talks about setting up the DB.

Everything I have found is either out of date or is not complete.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Would these SQL statments work?

[Link](http://www.postfix-tutorial.com/)

All of the posted postfix guides are awesome, I just need to the SQL table structures.

I was wondering if these would work.

Comment: What have you looked at that's out of date (so others won't post links to things you've already tried)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze), although it's for debian but I guess there are not much different.

Comment: I actually found that one and it seemed to really good, I think I am going to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Qmailrocks
http://qmailrocks.thibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the server guides at http://help.ubuntu.com to get started.  There are guides for setting up a mysql server there, and you may want to add a web server to host phpmyadmin.  The postfix section does not talk about using postfix with mysql, but reading it may still be helpful.  Most likely, just installing postfix-mysql and answering the questions will be enough to get you started with the email server side of things.

Answer (score 0):

The official postfix web site has *extensive* documentation.  http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html

For a basic configuration tutorial, read the Basic Configuration Readme: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

"Setting up the DB" is probably something too specific to be covered *in detail* in any tutorial.  Generally, you set up your mail server to match the DB, not the other way around, because the assumption is that you already have your user accounts (or other relevant info) in your database.  In any case, the MySQL Readem here http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html is going to be of great help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Go get a look here [Server-world](http://server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_11.04&p=mail&f=1), read, enjoy!

This web site is very usefull for install, configuration, use of most program you might need on a linux server!

Comment: Very interesting site.

Comment: indeed right ^^